# Datagridview Custom Cell Border and Custom Cell ForeColor

Tags: vb.net

Sorry If my question is too long but I have to explain before I ask.

I want to change the text color of the cell when meet the condition I set.

I also want to draw the horizontal line in every 2 rows and vertical line in every 5 cols.

I can do both of them separately. The problem is I can't get them both at the same time.

If I change the text first, the borders of the affected cells have disappeared.

If I draw the border first, the text colors change back to black(default).

**I have to change the text color and border color of the cells.**

My Codes are as follows:

```
Private Sub GridBorderLine(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs)
    'Declare Border Style and Border Color
    Dim vBStyle As ButtonBorderStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid
    Dim vBColor As Color = Color.Black

    'Custom Row Border (Horizontal)
    If e.RowIndex Mod 2 = False AndAlso e.RowIndex > 0 Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All - DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground)

        Dim H As Integer = 0
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, vBColor, 0, vBStyle, vBColor, 3, vBStyle, vBColor, 0, vBStyle, vBColor, 0, vBStyle)
        e.Handled = True
    End If

    'Custom Column Border (Vertical)
    If e.ColumnIndex Mod 5 = False AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then
         e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All - DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground)

        Dim W As Integer = 0
        If e.RowIndex Mod 2 = False And e.RowIndex > 0 Then W = 3 Else W = 0
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, vBColor, 3, vBStyle, vBColor, W, vBStyle, vBColor, 0, vBStyle, vBColor, 0, vBStyle)
        e.Handled = True
    End If

    'Custom Cell Color
    If e.FormattedValue.ToString.Contains(txt.Text) Then 
        CellColor(e)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CellColor(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs)
    Dim vLength as Integer = txt.Text.Length
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All - DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)

    If e.FormattedValue.ToString = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim vBeginning As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString.Substring(0, vLength)
    Dim vEnd As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString.Substring(vLength)

    Dim s As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.FormattedValue.ToString, vFont)
    Dim f As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(vBeginning, vFont)
    Dim b As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(vEnd, vFont)

    'Arrange Center Middle
    Dim w = e.CellBounds.X + ((e.CellBounds.Width - s.Width) / 2)
    Dim h = e.CellBounds.Y + ((e.CellBounds.Height - s.Height) / 2)

    Dim topLeft As New Point(w, h)
    Dim p As New Point(topLeft.X + (s.Width - b.Width), topLeft.Y)

   TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, vBeginning, vFont, topLeft, Color.Red)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, vEnd, vFont, p, Color.Blue)

    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you can try to change the text color in `CellFormatting Event`

Comment: thanks, now i can change my cell color in cellFormatting Event without affecting the cell borders

Comment: but i can't change the text color partially like before
(eg. the text in a cell is "01" and i want to change "0" to red and "1" to blue in that cell)

Comment: what do you mean `do you want to change text color partially`? can you share your method that you trying to change the text color partially?

Comment: i already gave my code above when i asked. you can copy this code and test for yourself. suppose a text in cell is (50) and you put (0) in textbox. So 0 is contain in that cell, the cellcolor method will change 5 to red and 0 to blue. put the above 2 methods i gave into datagridview_cellpainting event